# Links are not opening properly in the bottom frame

Tags: html

I am working with frames for the first time. Here is

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows="20%,*">
   <frame name="top" src="top.html" name="topmenu" />
   <frame name="main" src="content.html" name="content" />   
   <noframes>
   <body>
      Your browser does not support frames.
   </body>
   </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

**top.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <!-- begin navigation -->
    <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>                            
            <li><a href="contact.html" target="content">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation --> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**content.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
    Some Content
</body>
<html>
```

**contact.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
    Contact page
</body>
<html>
```

With this, the output is as under

[image]

Now when I click on the **Contact link**, instead of displaying the content in the content.html, it opens in a new tab as under

[image]

What is the mistake I am making. I believe there is some problem from my side in choosing the proper *target*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frames are *not supported* in HTML5 <sup>**^**</sup>, it is *deprecated*, and to get it working the `<!DOCTYPE>` *must* be set to either `HTML Frameset DTD` or `XHTML Frameset DTD`.

If you check the HTML setting in this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xhaxkfvt/) you'll see that I had set the DOCTYPE to "HTML 4.01 Frameset" in order to make it works, as in this image:

[image]

** *Also Note* that you have used the `name` attribute twice in each `frame` tag and there should be only one!

```
<frame name="top" src="top.html" name="topmenu" />
<frame name="main" src="content.html" name="content" />
```

---

<sup>**^**</sup> Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame

  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp